# Rename url from DB in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I made a website that contains products with the url: http://somesite.com/controller/function/brand_id/product_id. I would want to change those ID's to more search friendly names. All those ID are in the DB with a name. Is it possible to get those names out of the DB and put them in the URL? This because  i can't use the routing tool. The products and brands are dynamically and could be deleted or (name) changed at any time. So can't hardcode this into the routes.

Thanks for the effort

Comment: I guess, that's something for mod_rewrite, but I've never used it.

Comment: Check this out http://www.gwtindia.com/how-to-create-user-friendly-url-through-codeigniter/

Comment: If the brandnames and productnames for that brand are unique, you could just alter your method to accept names instead of ids.  Just search by name instead of id then.

Comment: If the names contain spaces or have accents, you could store an extra url-friendly and unique name per product and brand and search by that name.

Comment: The id's are unique in there own table. I have a table called brands, types and products. These are joined together on those ID numbers within products. Is it possible to get the values of those ID's from the tables types and brands and place those values as name in the url, from the routing config file? So to make a complete dynamicly generated routing system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by setting up some wildcard routes for `brand_id` and `product_id`. When you are performing the query for the product, you can just check to see if the URI segments are integers (IDs) or strings (names) and query the DB accordingly. I would store a URL-friendly version of the product name (replace spaces and special chars) and then query that, and also use that for generating links throughout the app.

**Update:** Here is a code sample for the logic you would want in the method that you are routing everything through:

```
public function search($brand, $product)
{
    if (is_int($brand))
    {
        // Look up the brand using an ID
        $this->db->where('id', $brand);
    }
    else
    {
        // Look up the brand based on the URI segment
        $this->db->where('uri_friendly_name', $brand);
    }

    // Do the same with adding conditionals for $product and then run the query
}
```

and here is an example of the route you would need:

```
$route['controller/function/(:any)/(:any)'] = "controller/search";
```

Comment: What i've done now is set-up the site url to somesite.com/products (routed to controller/function) but i can't seem to find the right function to get all values from DB (tables types and brands) within the routing config file. and replace the id's with the values. But like you said to make an extra field, how could i get those values displayed as link?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding your setup, but you wouldn't want to do it in the actual routes config file, you would want to do everything in your controller or model. I'll update my answer with a code sample.

Comment: Makes sense, this is the way to get started. Needed a lot of recoding, but this works just fine! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use several functions in your url using `_remap` Codeigniter built-in function:
Use the following function inside your controller:

```
public function _remap($method){
if ($method == 'project-name')
{
   //display project1
}
elseif($method == 'project-name2')
{
   //display project2
}
```

Another example using params:

```
public function _remap($method, $params = array())
{
    $method = 'process_'.$method;
    if (method_exists($this, $method))
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);
    }
    show_404();
}
```

`$method` is the `function` in your Url:
http://somesite.com/controller/function/brand_id/product_id

You can do the same for varying methods by extracting them from database

take a look here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping

Comment: This is to take controle about the whole controller / method assignment. What i want is to change de brand- and type_ID number to its defined Name which is saved in DB.  

But I didn't know this function existed, seems very usefull for other projects! Thank you very much!